# Is leaving debug sections in the source code a good practise?

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I am working together with a senior C++ developer. In most of his code he includes debug sections. It looks like this:

```
void do_something() {
    int var = 10

#ifndef NODEBUG
    trace("Function Start %s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif
    while (someCondition) {
        var += 1 
#ifndef NODEBUG 
    trace ("Var = %d \n", var)
#endif
    }
    ... (Do some other stuff)
    ... (Do some more stuff)

#ifndef NODEBUG
    trace("Function End %s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif 
}
```

I am not as experienced as he is, but these code snippets are all over the code and this really clogs the readability and the understandability. In my oppinion the preprocessor conditions should AT LEAST be properly intended with the rest of the code.

Is this practise something that I should form a habit of? I am not sure if this a good way but in my opinion this immensely bloats the code and should be left out.

Comment: this is more like an opinion from me: is very helpful to be able to print more info about how your tool is working and those Debug blocks are there for that....

Comment: Maybe the `#ifndef`could be moved inside `trace`. Depends on what `trace` is and how it is used elsewhere.

Comment: Why not just define trace as a debug only function, so it does nothing for release runs? FYI, you may want to use the standard preprocessor definitions `(NDEBUG, _DEBUG)`.

Comment: You could improve by moving `#ifdef` into `trace` or by writing a wrapper if `trace` is not owned by you. Other than that, while logging does get in a way of code readability, it's usefulness far outweight that loss.

Comment: _...clogs the readability..._ Well, this particular thing depends on which editor you're using. Like on VS Code, that block will have much lower transparency if you have defined `NODEBUG`. This question is clearly opinion based. I think that it will surely be helpful if you talk with your senior and try to understand his perspective behind putting those statements.

Comment: Nice. Nine lines of code for exactly zero thinking. They'll come in handy at the next negotiations for a payrise!

Comment: @churill that would suggest that one might have a `trace` and `debugTrace` - and still put the #ifs away.  I wouldn't say it needs to depend on other uses of trace at all

Comment: @UKMonkey Maybe `trace` is not always used with `#ifndef...`, then a wrapper function would be necessary.

Comment: @churill I don't really care about that maybe.  Start with one file - make that neat; clean up the rest as you go forward.  At the end, maybe there's a bulk search and replace, until then, why let a maybe get in the way of improving code?

Comment: Notably, all safety-/mission-critical software bands having debug code or non-executed code anywhere in the program. The concern is not so much about debug code turning everything into an unreadable mess, but rather that debug code left behind by mistake is an extremely common bug.

Comment: The "pro tip" here is to not create an unreadable pre-processor jungle, but instead handle this through version control. Make a debug branch and maintain the debug code separately. Saves your production code from looking like utter trash.

Comment: Also, if your supposed experienced senior dev insists on writing code like this and you can't use version control, they should write two separate functions and #ifdef those two as whole. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/8M577Y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not generally a bad practice to add code within debug sections.
As long as this code doesn't fundamentally change the behavior of your function, it doesn't add much complexity and can give you useful information. However, it does decrease readability.

It is very rare that you really need a dedicated code section that only runs on debug builds. What I **very** commonly do myself instead is create specialized macros that only perform an action on debug builds. This ends up being much more concise and readable. For example:

```cpp
// defined in some utility header
#ifndef NODEBUG
#define DEBUG_TRACE(...) trace(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG_TRACE(...)
#endif

void do_something() {
    int var = 10

    DEBUG_TRACE("Function Start %s", __FUNCTION__);

    while (someCondition) {
        var += 1
        DEBUG_TRACE("Var = %d \n", var);
    }
    // ... (Do some other stuff)
    // ... (Do some more stuff)

    DEBUG_TRACE("Function End %s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

If you were to add a `#ifndef NODEBUG` code section now, it would become much more obvious that you are changing the behavior of the function instead of just logging something.

This practice can be applied not only to logging but to assertions and other things which only compile on debug builds. If you do this a lot, then the following macros can be of help too:

```cpp
#ifndef NODEBUG
#define IF_DEBUG_ELSE(expr, alt) expr
#define IF_DEBUG(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IF_DEBUG_ELSE(expr, alt) alt
#define IF_DEBUG(...)
#endif

void example(int x) {
    IF_DEBUG_ELSE(/* action on debug builds */, /* action on release builds */);
    IF_DEBUG(/* one-liner action only on debug builds */); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is really helpful! Is there a similar way for python code?

Comment: @Ceph python doesn't have a preprocessor that allows you to just completely remove code sections, so unfortunately no. You could make a global constant called `NODEBUG` though and write a `debug_trace` function that only logs if this variable is `False`. This function will likely be optimized out by the JIT-compiler if `NODEBUG` is `True`, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: @JanSchultke python doesn't have a jit compiler either

Answer (score 6):

> Is leaving debug sections in the source code a good practise?

```
#ifndef NODEBUG
    trace("Function End %s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif
```

There is no hard and fast rule of whether debug code should be removed. Sometime it's a common sense and up to the person who writes the code to decide.

Clearly for your example, it's trivial enough to delete those debug code out for readability.

However, some/many debug code is not trivial. It takes time to write. And some time it's very important for a developer to re-enable those code to track and debug some real problem when it happens. In those cases, it's clearly very useful to keep those debug code in for later usage/debugging.

Comment: However, if the debug code is not trivial, it should probably be factored out into a separate function. Like a function that prints the structure of a tree. Or similar. These have a right to exist even when they are not called from anywhere, but they won't clutter up the code at all the places where the programmer found it useful to see the structure of the tree.

Comment: I've seen some really complicated debug logging in place that is not really convenient to put in separate function though